# Can I partially refund a 4-pack bought on Steam?

Tags: steam

I bought the 4 pack for Orion: Prelude and planned to gift the copy to my friends. I gave one of the copy but he can't seem to download it.

How can i refund the last 2 copy in my inventory without refunding the one in my library and the one in my friends library?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Steam Refunds](http://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds) you can't do that. You can only refund full bundles and only if none of the items are transferred.

> Refunds on Bundles
>
> You can receive a full refund for any bundle purchased on the Steam Store, so long as none of the items in the bundle have been transferred, and if the combined usage time for all items in the bundle is less than two hours. If a bundle includes an in-game item or DLC that is not refundable, Steam will tell you if the whole bundle is refundable during check-out.

Comment: less than 2 hours ?

Comment: @BoomPow31 Well that's the official steam refund policy, so you can't just complete a game then get a refund. But your problem is that you transferred one of the game to friend. You can't refund because you can only refund the whole package, one piece of the package is no longer yours.